# Transitividade Verbal

Tags: verbos

Olá, minha duvida é sobre transitividade verbal.

A oração:

> Obedeça-me.

é transitiva indireta. Por qual razão ela adquire essa qualificação?

Comment: Bem-vindo! Onde viste que a oração é transitiva indireta? Lá não explicava o motivo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Primeiramente, não sei se é correto dizer que a oração é transitiva. Ao meu ver, quem é transitivo ou não é o verbo.

E quanto à sua dúvida, um verbo é [intransitivo](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/intransitivo/) se não precisa de um complemento (por exemplo, o verbo funcionar: "o computador funciona").

Senão, o verbo é [transitivo](https://michaelis.uol.com.br/moderno-portugues/busca/portugues-brasileiro/transitivo/), ou seja, precisa de um complemento. Por exemplo, abrir: "ela abriu" é uma frase incompleta, pois é necessário dizer o que foi aberto (o complemento do verbo). Uma frase completa seria "ela abriu a porta".

Mas quando um verbo é transitivo, o complemento verbal (por exemplo, "a porta") pode precisar ou não de uma preposição. Se a preposição não for necessária, ou seja, se o complemento vier diretamente após o verbo, então dizemos que é transitivo direto, caso contrário, transitivo indireto.

Por exemplo:

*"Ele comemora a conquista".*  (a conquista é o complemento, não há preposição, portanto, comemorar é transitivo direto).

*"Ele conversa **com** as pessoas".* ("as pessoas" é o complemento e há a preposição *com*, logo, o verbo conversar é transitivo indireto).

*"O pai contou a história ao filho".* ("a história" é o complemento direto, pois não é precedido de preposição, e "o filho" é o complemento indireto, pois aparece logo após a preposição "a", por isso, contar é um verbo transitivo direto e indireto).

Comment: E quanto ao verbo obedecer em "obedeça-me", onde está a resposta ?

Comment: Obedecer é sempre um verbo transitivo indireto, pois obedece-se a alguém, nesse caso "a mim", mas ao invés de escrever "obedeça a mim" escreveu-se "obedeça-me", da mesma forma que ao invés de dizer "ela deu um presente para mim" dizemos "ela *me* deu um presente".

Comment: "Obedecer é sempre um verbo transitivo indireto, pois...."   Verbos transitivos indiretos não admitem a voz passiva.  Como explicar "Mantenha-me informado se todas  as minhas ordens foram obedecidas"

Comment: @Centaurus essa é uma boa pergunta. A única explicação que sempre me deram é que "obedecer" é uma das exceções dessa regra. Você conhece outra? Obrigado.

Comment: @Centaurus Os verbos *obedecer* e *desobedecer* são exceções e por isso permite a voz passiva (mesmo sendo V.T.I.).